# Bootstrap css causing form submit to goto page top?

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation, sitefinity

Using a sitefinity site (v7.1.5), we have a link ref in the masterpage to bootstrap cdn.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

We're having an issue with a form that's halfway down on the homepage. When it's submitted, the page jumps back to the top even if there's form validation errors, therefore the user assumes the form was sent since they can't see the errors unless they scroll down. I found out by trial & error that if I take out the bootstrap css link, the form stays put after submit is clicked. Can anyone explain what's causing this?

http://tinyurl.com/pxfduf4

Answer (score 0):

try use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

without https:

Comment: Made no difference. Page still returns to top after submit.

Comment: and if you try to put the code inside header tag? without https: ... i've try and works

Answer (score 0):

Sitefinty from all my expierience does that with or without bootstrap

Comment: Not true, as stated in the OP, as soon as I take out the bootstrap ref, the form stays scrolled down and shows the form errors.